# UL has margin on the left

Tags: css, html-lists, space

For some reason in my footer there's a space to the left of my ul so it isn't lined up with the content above it (membership text etc) If I were to put text outside this ul (but still within the footer wrapper) there is no such space.

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ozanam Club </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts/enigma.css" />

</head>

<body>

<div id="wrap">
    <header>
        <div id="logo"><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" height="157px" width="237px"></a></div>
    <!--
    <div class="social">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icons/facebook.gif"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icons/twitter.gif"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icons/youtube.gif"/></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    -->
        <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Clubs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">F.A.Q</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </div>

    </header>

     <section class="slider">
        <div class="flexslider">
          <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <img src="images/slider/image1.gif" />
                </li>
                <li>
                <img src="images/slider/image2.gif" />
                </li>
                <li>
                <img src="images/slider/image3.gif" />
                </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>

    <div class="main">
        <h1>Ozanam Club</h1>
        <p>The first Ozanam Club was started in May 1989 by James Lynch, a member of the
St. Vincent De Paul society who himself had two children with learning difficulties 
and who was concerned at the general lack of leisure provision for them.</p>
<p>The Ozanam Club is a Special Works Conference of the St. vincent De Paul Society.
The name of the clubs are called after Blessed Frederick Ozanam who is the founder
of the S.S.V.P. At this present time we have two clubs in Viewpark, an adults club
and a seperate club for younger members. We have an adults club in Hamilton and 
Paisley and also a club in Carfin for younger members. </p>
        <h1>Membership</h1>
        <p>Membership is open to anyone who has disablities, regardless of their race or religious belief.</p>
<p>The aim of the clubs are a fun night out for our members and some temporary respite for parents. All of the clubs are run solely by volunteers who are disclosure checked prior to working with
vulnerable adults/children.</p><p> They are also made aware of the Adults/Children Protection Procedures and encouraged to attend an information session.</p>
<p>You can find more information on our a <a href="#">F.A.Q page.</a></p>

    </div>
<div class="side">
  <img src="images/events.gif" alt="Events" />
  <a href="#" class="button">View</a>
</div>

<div class="side">
  <img src="images/photos.gif" alt="Events" />
  <a href="#" class="button">View</a>
</div>

</div>
<footer>
  <div id="footer-wrap">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Clubs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">F.A.Q</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
</footer>    


  </div>
  </div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {background: white; background: url('../images/grunge.png'); font-family: 'EnigmaticRegular';}
#wrap {margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; max-width: 1000px;}

header {position: relative;}

#logo {margin: 20px 0 0 0; display: block; float: left;}

.social ul { z-index: 1; list-style: none; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;}
.social li { float: left;}
.social img { height: 35px; width: 35px;}

#navigation {  width: 100%; max-width: 1000px; height: 200px; position: relative; }
#navigation ul {  padding: 0.5em; background: white; border-radius: 5px; border-bottom: solid 3px #3c88bc; display: inline-block; position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;}
#navigation li { padding-left: 0.5em; padding-right: 0.5em; list-style: none; font-style: none; font-family: 'EnigmaticBold'; border-right: solid 1px black;}
#navigation li:last-child { border: 0;}
#navigation ul, 
#navigation li {float: left;}

#navigation a { color: #195c8a; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold;}
#navigation a:hover { color: #13405f;}

.main { float: left; margin-top: 20px; width: 625px;}
.main h1 {font-family: 'EnigmaticBold'; color: #13405f; }
.main p {color: #13405f;}
.main a {color: inherit; }

.side {float: right; margin-top: 20px; border-radius: 10px; margin-bottom: 10%; }
.side a { text-decoration: none; color: #3c88bc;}
.button { font-size: 14px;font-family: 'EnigmaticBold'; display: block; width: 100px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; background: #fff; padding: 5px; border-radius: 10px; border-bottom: solid 3px #3c88bc;}

footer { height: 100px; background: #195c8a; clear: both; }
#footer-wrap {margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; width: 100%; max-width: 1000px; }
#footer-wrap li { float: left; list-style: none; padding-right: 3em;}
#footer-wrap a {color: white ;text-decoration: none;}
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The `<ul>` element has browser inherent padding & margin by default. In your case, Use

```
#footer ul {
    margin: 0; /* To remove default bottom margin */ 
    padding: 0; /* To remove default left padding */
}
```

or a CSS browser reset ( https://cssreset.com/ ) to deal with this.

Comment: This is a decent answer but FYI to others that this method is destructive: it resets margin on top, right and bottom, also, although the OP question was about left margin only.

Comment: working on `padding-x` solves my problem

Answer (score 7):

I don't see any `margin` or `margin-left` declarations for `#footer-wrap li`.

This ought to do the trick:

```
#footer-wrap ul,
#footer-wrap li {
    margin-left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: I was certain I tried that.. but thank you, it works fine now!

Answer (score 7):

by default `<UL/>` contains default padding

therefore try adding style to `padding:0px` in css class or inline css